# Multipart request in sprinboot doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, httprequest, multipartform-data, binary-data

The question might be silly for you all, but I beat my head since 1 week to get one issue resolved in my spring-boot application.

I have developed one API to read a file which is multipart, sent from many clients.

I tested the api through postman which rendered me expected result, but when I called the API from the client it was not even reaching to the spring boot controller..

here is how my code looks in springboot

```
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/v2")

public class PDFExtractController {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@RequestMapping(value = "/document/{DocType}",method =RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes =MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )
public ResponseEntity fileUpload(@PathVariable("DocType") String docType, @RequestParam("pdf") MultipartFile multipartfiles, @RequestParam(name ="provider", required=false) String AcceptProvider, @RequestParam(name= "verbose", required=false) String AcceptVerbose,@RequestParam(name= "pdf_password",required=false) String AcceptPass, HttpServletRequest request){
boolean isMultipartContent = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

        String provider = null;
        String password = null;
        boolean verbose= false;

        try{
            MultipartFile uploadedFile = multipartfiles;
            if(uploadedFile!=null){
                String fieldname = uploadedFile.getName();

                if(AcceptProvider!=null){
                    provider=AcceptProvider.trim();
                    SplunkMgr.addtoMDC(MDCFieldNames.PROVIDER.getValue(), provider.trim());
                }

                if(AcceptVerbose!=null){
                    verbose = "true".equals(AcceptVerbose.trim());
                }

                if (PESConstants.PARAM_PDF.equals(fieldname)) {
                    file = uploadedFile.getBytes();
                }

                if(AcceptPass!=null){
                    password=AcceptPass.trim();
                    SplunkMgr.addtoMDC(MDCFieldNames.PASSWORD_PROVIDED.getValue(), String.valueOf(password != null));
                }
            }
        }// Network problem
        catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Network error when receiving request.", e);
            PDFExtractResult pdfExtractResult = new PDFExtractResult().markInError(PdfExtractReferenceMgr.instance().getMessage(MessageConstants.InvitcoMsgCode.PES_NETWORK_ERROR));
            responseData = PdfServletMgr.createResponseJson(pdfExtractResult, verbose);
        }
//---here is my code to process the file and sending the response----

}
```

But my client sends like below

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new 
URL(url).openConnection();

    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
"form-data; boundary=" + boundary);




SplunkMgr.instance().addSplunkMessage("Calling PES Service with 
userId = " + userId, LogLevel.INFO);
    }
    else{

        try {
            SplunkMgr.instance().addSplunkMessage("Could not get user context from logged in user " , LogLevel.INFO);
            new MappingSysAdminServiceImpl().logout();
        } catch (SAMException e) {
            SplunkMgr.instance().addSplunkMessage("Logout Failed - Unexpected error when logging out. " + (e !=null ? e.getMessage() : e), LogLevel.ERROR);
        }
    }
    if(autoMapper!=null)
        // here header data setting

    OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, CHARSET), false);

    // Add params
    if (providerId != null && providerId.length() > 0) {
        addParam(writer, boundary, PESConstants.PARAM_PROVIDER, providerId);
    }
    if (verbose) {
        addParam(writer, boundary, PESConstants.PARAM_VERBOSE, "true");
    }
    if (password != null && password.length() > 0) {
        addParam(writer, boundary, PESConstants.PARAM_PASSWORD, password);
    }

    // Send file
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: multipart/form-data; name=\""+PESConstants.PARAM_PDF+"\"").append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Type: application/pdf").append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF);


    writer.append(CRLF).flush();
    output.write(pdfFile);
    output.flush(); // Important before continuing with writer!
    writer.append(CRLF).flush(); // CRLF is important! It indicates end of boundary.

    // End of multipart/form-data.
    writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF).flush();

    // Read response
    InputStream input = null;
```

Your help would really help me to goahead..

Note: If I use springboot multipart I'm able to run without any hurdle and get output. problem is when I hit from client...

Please suggest me what changes I have to do so that I can proceed

In the controller I have @RequestParam so it was not going inside the controller then I realised client sends the form data so I changed to @FormDataParam of jersy and got the MultiPart but I got nothing in it.

@FormDataParam(PESConstants.PARAM_PDF) InputStream inputStream

I didn't get any error but: I got null in the InputStream object

Comment: You have your controller method as `consumed = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`, which is `multipart/form-data`.  But your client is sending the data just as `form-data; boundary=...`.  Have you tried including `multipart` in the client's `Content-Type` header?

Comment: I tried that too @user2478398  but same issue.. thanks

Comment: *it was not even reaching to the spring boot controller..* Do you mean that method is not invoked or multipartfiles param is empty/null ?

Comment: Hi Antoniosses, It is reaching to the controller if and only if I change it to @FormDataPatam with multipart as null.. or else it is not even reaching to the controller